# excel vba paste screenshot in ms paint

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have a vba code that will take a screenshot in a website, and I would like to paste it in MS PAINT then copy again to paste in MS ACCESS database. Right now Im trying to paste the screenshot on MS PAINT but its not working.

Here's the part of my code where I'll do a screenshot then open mspaint to paste:

```
keybd_event VK_MENU, 0, 0, 0
keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, 0, 0
keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0
keybd_event VK_MENU, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0

'open mspaint
Shell "C:\windows\system32\mspaint.exe", 1

Application.SendKeys "^V"
```

Comment: Where are you doing the copy?

Comment: The code will execute a screenshot command that's why there will be no copy thing. after screenshot on the website, the code will open the MS PAINT, then the screenshot on the clipboard should be pasted there.

Comment: This works for you? 'open mspaint
Shell "C:\windows\system32\mspaint.exe"
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
AppActivate "Untitled - Paint"

Comment: My code on opening mspaint already works but Im actually looking for a code that will allow me to paste my screenshot on ms paint since Applciation.sendkeys is not working.

Comment: It's because it opens but it's not active, hence, the ctrl+v is sent to nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

Digging a little more, this should work

```
'your code to get the screenshot
Dim WshShell as Object
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "mspaint"
 Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")

WshShell.AppActivate "Paint"
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")

WshShell.SendKeys "^(v)"
 Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
```

Comment: How can i use .AppActivate? its not working in my code.

Comment: You need to add the library"WScript" in references if not using my variable Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell"), the code as it is should work, or at least it did for me.